# Why doesnt it print the array in the second loop like it does in the first one?

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop, printf

The programme below prints the array `hello` correctly in the first loop. But in the second one all it prints is `o`. Of course the integer `k` is pointless but I used it because I thought that the reason probably was that I used the `i` in the first for loop

I was expecting to get `hello` x2 but instead I took `hello` and `o`. I still dont understand why this is happening and honestly I am trying to figure this out for over an hour and I am stuck

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int plus = 0;
    char s[20] = "hello";
    strlen(s);
    int a = strlen(s);
    int count[strlen(s) - 1];
    int k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
        if (s[i] == ' ')
            continue;
        else {
            for (j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                if (s[i] == s[j]) {
                    plus++;
                    count[i] = plus;
                }
            }
        }
        plus = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // find max/es counts
    for (k = 0; k < a; k++) {
        printf("%c", s[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

well the purpose of the program doesn't really matter, I just want help to understand why the `printf` gives this output.

Comment: There's no difference between the two code snippets. Why did you post it twice?

Comment: `int count[strlen(s)-1];` WHy did you subtract 1? You'll write out of bounds on the last iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: The out of bounds array reference is probably overwriting `a`, so the second loop doesn't iterate the correct number of times.

Answer (score 1):

This program invokes undefined behaviour when you assign `count[i]=plus;` and `i==a`.

You need to remove `-1` from the definition.#

Some additional notes:

1. Use the correct type for sizes - ie `size_t` instead of `int`
2. Use meaningful variable names instead of `a`, `i`, `j`, `k` ....
3. Your line `strlen(s);` without using the returned value makes no sense

```
    size_t plus=0;
    char text[20]="hello";
    size_t textLength=strlen(text);
    size_t count[textLength];
```

Answer (score 0):

I use GDB debug your code,and I discoverd some interesting information.

```
(gdb) p s
$2 = "hello", '\000' <repeats 14 times>

(gdb) p /x (unsigned int)s
$5 = 0xffffd340

(gdb) p /x (unsigned int)count
$6 = 0xffffd330
(gdb) p /x count[4]
$7 = 0x6c6c6568
```

The memory address of `s` is `0xffffd340`,and the memory address of `count` is `0xffffd330`.

`0xffffd340 - 0xffffd330 = 0x10`.

How many elements dose `count` have?

`strlen(s) - 1`,according to your code,`int count[strlen(s) - 1];`.

The value of `s` is "hello",so `count` has `5-1=4` elements.

The size of each element of count is 4 bytes.`count` occupies 4 bytes,and the   memory addresses of 4 bytes are `0xffffd330,0xffffd334,0xffffd338,0xffffd33c,0xffffd340`.

The address of last element of count is `0xffffd340`.If run `count[4] = 5`,data in `0xffffd340-0xffffd341-0xffffd342-0xffffd343` will be `5-0-0-0`.

`0xffffd340` is also the memory address of s.data in data in `0xffffd340-0xffffd341-0xffffd342-0xffffd343-0xffffd344` is `h-e-l-l-o`.

`count[4] = 5` overwrite data in `0xffffd340-0xffffd341-0xffffd342-0xffffd343`,and the value of s becomes `5-0-0-0-o`.

Here is the log suppied by GDB.

```
(gdb) p s
$14 = "\005\000\000\000o", '\000' <repeats 14 times>
```

Modfying `int count[strlen(s) - 1];` to `int count[strlen(s)];` or Commenting  `count[i] = plus;` will fix your bug.